# Include header when chunks are fetched with code splitting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, header, code-splitting

I've used code splitting to seprate restricted parts of my app into different chunks. This is working great so far, now I would like to ensure that the files themselves don't get served unless authenticated. I was thinking of using **ngx_http_auth_request_module**

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html#auth_request

Which allows to send a sub-request before serving certain files. How can I ensure that certain headers are always send as part of the HTTP request when React wants to fetch the necessary chunks?

Comment: why do you want to authenticate these requests since they are public assets?

Comment: @guilherme-santiago because it shouldn't be public ‍♂️

Comment: then it shouldn't be in your client-side logic

Comment: @GuilhermeSantiago Well exactly, but the client still needs to request something to display it. The logic (who is authenticated and who isn't) happens on the server, yet the client needs to send something to identify the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have trouble understanding why you would need to prevent unauthenticated malicious users to have access to your static chunks.

Dynamic imports and code splitting are mainly used to reduce the bundle size for large applications as users won't necessarily need everything.

In order to secure your app you need to prevent users from seeing or tampering with data they do not have access to. This means the security lies with the API your app is talking to.

What I do:

- Reject unauthenticated requests to the API
- Keep a token client-side on authentication
- Pass and check the token on all requests
- Burn the token when obsolete and redirect to login
- Notify, redirect users when they do not have access to some data or better not displaying content they do not have access to

I'm sure you already did what I wrote above, what I want to emphasize is that chunks are basically empty UI filled with data from the secured API.

Let's say I have bad intentions and I bypass client-side routing in order to have access to the restricted chunk. It will be an empty UI with secured API routes, I won't be able to do anything with it.

In case you have a very specific need, you might need to write a webpack plugin.

Comment: Indeed, all of the things above are already implemented. This is supposed to add additional security hygiene. While it's just an empty UI, it still tells the users more than they should maybe know. In general, I see the advantage there that it reduces the possible attack surface. I think writing a webpack plugin will be the way to go.

Comment: Accepted your answer because the need of Webpack plugin seems inevitable.

Answer (score 1):

### about the ensure request

One of webpack 's properties is that it can fetch only necessary chunks when loading pages.You can just use like require.ensurn to query chunks when necessary,so there is no need to ensure the certain headers.

### ngx_http_auth_request_module

Ngx_http_auth_request_module and sub-request are always used to fetch web file in server.It's always used as backend authentication module.Here is the data flow direction in nginx.

When you download file, the download request will be passed to the server, then server return the override Http Request to Nginx,then Nginx will find the exact file.

The ngx_http_auth_request_module allows to send request to back server(like php .tomcat), and based on the request to pass or not, if pass, you will be able to fetch file in the back server.

### nginx-----load speed

The nginx always fetch static file, like index.html.If have to validate the permission for every js/css everytime,then fetch it throw,thd loading speed for page will be very slow.

### about how to authenticate

Since you have separated app.Here is a little suggestions.You can get the authenticated request by only import restricted parts in the authenticated file.And the webpack will automatically handle the rest.

1. fetch data from the server in the non-restricted part with information to authenticate like this:

   http://.../api/auth?info=...
2. based on the infos in server to authenticate, and pass other infos like type back to the frontend
3. based on the type information to view .

---

```
if (this.props.type === "restrict"){   
   <restrict component/>
} else {
   <non-restrict component/>
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, though… the authentication happens in the non-restricted part, like a LoginComponent, what the server returns needs to be passed to nginx again when trying to fetch the restricted parts. And this is where I see the problem, either I split the app completely and just load a different page altogether or I pass the cookie somehow into the headers when fetching the chunks.

Comment: @Mahoni I have changed about how to authenticate.

Comment: This won't suffice. Webpack will indeed split app both parts into two or more chunk files. Yet in the source code of the non-restricted part you can still find the chunk file names and just HTTP GET them yourself, hence that part is not really protected. It's obscured or a little bit more hidden at most.

That's why I was explicitly asking, if or how I can add a mechanism to send additional header when those chunks are fetched.